# Google maps (google.maps.LatLng) change values lat lng

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hello guys i have a problem when i use the method  google.maps.LatLng every time i use it automatically change the longitude value to a different value , that is too long to use in Google map so i can not add markers with location in my map.Does anybody know a different way to do it or what the problem is.I reatrive the data from a json sting and load it to an array check the code below.

My latitude and longitude

[image: lat,lng]

After  use google.maps.LatLng latitude and longitude 
[image: google.maps.LatLng]

```
var map;
var markers = [];
var child_details = [];

function initialize() {
    var haightAshbury = new google.maps.LatLng(34.8055973, 32.4104341);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: haightAshbury,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);

    // This event listener will call addMarker() when the map is clicked.
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        addMarker(event.latLng);
    });
}


function load_children(child_list) {

    var marker;
    var obj = JSON.parse(child_list);

    for (var i in obj) {
        child_details.push([obj[i].cid, obj[i].uid, obj[i].Name, obj[i].Surname,
            obj[i].lat, obj[i].lng, obj[i].timestamp,
            obj[i].Sensor
        ]);
    }

    setUpMarkers(map, child_details);
}


function setUpMarkers(map, locations) {

    alert('set up');
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var loc = locations[i];
        alert("lat" + loc[4] + "lng " + loc[5]);
        //The problem is here
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(loc[4], loc[5]);
        //After i use this method to get Lat Lng i get wrong lng
        alert(myLatLng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: loc[3]

        });
        markers.push(marker);
    }

}


// Add a marker to the map and push to the array.
function addMarker(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);

}

// Sets the map on all markers in the array.
function setAllMap(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        alert('adding marker' + markers[i]);
        markers[i].setMap(map);
    }
}

// Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
function clearMarkers() {
    setAllMap(null);
}

// Shows any markers currently in the array.
function showMarkers() {
    setAllMap(map);
}

// Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
function deleteMarkers() {
    clearMarkers();
    markers = [];
}
```

Comment: try wrapping the values in `parseFloat` when you construct your latLng, i.e. `var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(loc[4]), parseFloat(loc[5]));`

Comment: Do you mean the coordinate gets truncated so the marker doesn't accurately locate the precise spot?

Comment: What do you mean by 'too long to use in Google map'? it doesn't matter it is long, google maps will ignore other decimal places. I think your error is somewhere else. What doesn't work in your application? Does it throw some error?

Comment: duncan. Thanks but the problem  is arise after i use google.maps.LatLng.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates showed are exactly the same as for GoogleMaps precision concerns.

The precision is only 6 decimals, whichever decimal after that is not taken into account for positioning a marker in the Map.

See toUrlValue(precision?:number) here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng

Comment: Ok guys  thanks , i will check if the problem is caused by something else.